# SurfaceView rotation problem

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a situation where I am using `SurfaceView` fro recording an Video. But when I try to record in portrait mode, the `surfaceView` shows me the preview in landscape mode. Is there a way that i could rotate the `surfaceView` or make my camera to rotate at an angle of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is Camera surface works properly only in landscpe mode. As far as I know only last release of SDK corrects that feature. But while the most phones use 2.2, 2.3 now you should use landscape orientation for camera activity. There is one problem here. You will have to rotate you result video afterall.

There are couple hacks to avoid this featue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly) but they don't work on all devices and I can't suggest using them.