# How to change a camera orientation in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-orientation

//here is my code

```
  if (mPreviewRunning) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;`
```

when i was open my camera its only show in landscape mode.
how to change in portrait mode...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Android camera orientation properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRIAT);
```