# lock your camera view to landscape mode in android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I want to lock my **camera view** to "**Landscape**" mode.When I click on the simple button in my app, that time device's camera will open and and that **camera should be locked** to "**Landscape mode**". Can anyone know the solution of this problem?

I am using this code inside "CaptureImageActivity.java" activity.
So after execution of this activity my system's camera will open.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore. ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


            startActivityForResult(i,1000);

        }
    });
```

And I want to lock that camera view to "LandScape Mode". And as per solution

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureImageActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Only "CaptureImageActivity" activity is locked to "LandScape Mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your activity inside manifest file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Can i use this if am using the default camera of Android ?

Comment: i want to lock camera view to potraite

Answer (score 1):

see this link to lock your camera orientation,use `setDisplayOrientation (int degrees)`

documentation can be found on following link :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29

for more details see this answer :

[How to set Android camera orientation properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)

Answer (score 0):

```
By using setCameraDisplayOrientation=
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```