# Camera orientation is not displaying in proper mode android

Tags: android, camera

I am using custom camera and surface view. But the problem is the camera orientation is not displaying in proper mode.

I tried with this code:

```
Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
parameters.set("rotation", 90);
c.setParameters(p);
```

and also with this code:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mRotation); 

But no effect. If there any other solution for this. Please tell me.
```

Comment: I went through the code and i think this will help you [Check This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) works perfectly for me on the devices i tested, with one notable exception (it's quite a long shot but it might explain your issue): the Samsung Galaxy Ace, on which this function does not work as expected.

Comment: I am testing on Samsung Galaxy Ace and Samsung Galaxy Y.

Comment: Thanks. As per you suggestion I tested on HTC one and Also LG and work perfectly with this code. if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");parameters.set("rotation",90);}

Comment: How did you fix the problem on the Galaxy Ace? I'm having that issue right now.

Comment: As far as I know, you just can't fix it: it's mostly a hardware problem.
It might be possible to re-code manually a function that does that, but I guess the performance would be very bad. And it's probably not an easy task either...

Comment: Hi, did anyone managed to fix the problem on the Galaxy Ace device? Thanks in advance.