# android startVideo stretched and in landscape mode

Tags: android, video, camera

I have some problem in my code. I must start camera and capture it , so here is my code, and my problem is that camera starting with some strange view, like landscape mode and stretched.

```
 mVideoCaptureView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = mVideoCaptureView.getHolder();
        videoCaptureViewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        videoCaptureViewHolder.addCallback(new Callback() {
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                startVideo();
            }

            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });
```

and the `startVideo()` function

```
private void startVideo() {
        if(mCamera != null) return;
        SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = null;
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("CameraTest", "Camera Open filed");
            return;
        }
        mCamera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
            }
        }); 
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        if (null != mVideoCaptureView)
            videoCaptureViewHolder = mVideoCaptureView.getHolder();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(videoCaptureViewHolder);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }

        try {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Also I must add my own `buttons` , `ImageButtons` in camera view
Thanks
Regards 
sorry for English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some function for `Camera` `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)