# android set the preview orientation

Tags: android, camera

my question is about the camera in android ,I wonder if I can set the orientation of preview of camera,How could I set this in `android 1.6+` versions.thanks for your answer.

EDIT:
thanks for your answers,
now I want to know how to save the image depend on its oriention message,after I get the byte[],I want to realize app can save the jpg. image fit its length and height.now I　write the byte[] directly in the file and the size isn't right.If I use Vertical mode then the image  should be more height but it doesn't .Could anyone help me please?thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
preview.set("orientation", "portrait");
preview.set("rotation",90);
```

and

```
preview.set("orientation", "landscape");          
preview.set("rotation", 90);
```

See this thread for a more detailed answer:

[How to set Android camera orientation properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)