# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, memory-leaks

I am trying to use opencv in android.After so many difficulties i finally manage to run it in my device.But unfortunately it is not working.When i am trying to capture the image i am facing two problem:-
1.The camera is showing 90 degree horizontal.
2.When i click "capture" it is getting crashed.

Here is my code:

```
/** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                findViewById(R.id.img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
                findViewById(R.id.preview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (pg != null)
                    pg.dismiss();
                ok_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                click_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try_again_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                findViewById(R.id.img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
                findViewById(R.id.preview).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (pg != null)
                    pg.dismiss();
                ok_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                click_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try_again_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
```

The error in the logcat :

```
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:430)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:447)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at org.opencv.face.Sample3Native$4.onPictureTaken(Sample3Native.java:209)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:687)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
07-02 15:31:51.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30198):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You might want to post [some](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [code](http://www.sscce.org) so people can see what you're doing and what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that the issue is that you're running out of memory because of the great consumption which is usual image processing app.
The bitmap what you get after the picture might be much bigger than you actually need to show it on the screen.

Here are some ideas to optimize memory:

1. use a less memory expensive Bitmap format, i.e. Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
2. use BitmapOptions and then decode your stream of bytes reusing a preallocated Bitmap within inBitmap when you know that you're using the same sizes.
3. use BitmapOptions and use an inSampleSize bigger than 1

Other ideas to solve your issue, but not related to memory consumption
 4. take pictures at lower resolution changing the CameraParameters;
 5. use the [setOneShotPreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) (I assume that you still take picture and use onPictureTaken) although it may happen (depending on the device and on camera parameters) that what you see on the display is not what it's actually taken on the picture.

Here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html):

A quick example of BitmapOptions usage
    // Somewhere at the beginning of the activity
    Camera.Parameters params = this.camera.getParameters();
    Size pictureSize = params.getPictureSize();

```
this.bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
this.bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
this.bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
this.bitmapOptions.inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

//  In onPictureTaken function
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, bitmapOptions);
```

Regarding your issue of 90 degrees orientation: it may be due to a specific device behaviour
[How to set Android camera orientation properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)
but it would be nice if you can provide more details.