# How set Orientation the same default Camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

These are result capture image from 4 trend of Phone by Default Camera
[image: These are result capture image from 4 trend by Default Camera]

These are result capture image from 4 trend of Phone by my app.
[image: These are result capture image from 4 trend by my app]

How set Orientation the same default Camera? thanks all.

Comment: Did you try this solution:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6991886/1384010

Comment: and for different device versions try this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/5140988/1384010

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: @D T do you want to set the same orientation as of image captured from camera , in the image which you are going to display ??

Comment: i setting mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);, but this code change preview of camera. so this value can't change to other value.

Comment: It's not clear how you achieved 4 different orientations on the picture sequence.